# Unable to send email from SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, email

I am trying to send an email from SQL Server to Trigger. I have performed as per the guidance in [this](http://surajpassion.in/sending-email-using-stored-procedures-in-sql-server/) blog. Whenever I am trying as email, I am getting an error.

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sysmail_add_account_sp
    @account_name = 'ChandreshTestAccount'
  , @description = 'Sending email from test account'
  , @email_address = 'chandresh.cmk@gmail.com'
  , @display_name = 'No-Reply'
  , @replyto_address = 'chandresh.cmk@gmail.com'
  , @mailserver_name = 'smtp.gmail.com'
  , @port = 25
  , @username = 'chandresh.cmk@gmail.com'
  , @password = 'xxxxxxx'
Go
```

> Error: The mail could not be sent to the recipients because of the
>   mail server failure. (Sending Mail using Account 6
>   (2017-02-02T14:24:46). Exception Message: Could not connect to mail
>   server. (A connection attempt failed because the connected party did
>   not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection
>   failed because connected host has failed to respond 74.125.68.109:25).
>   )

Then I have tried to change the port number 587 and got the below error.

> The mail could not be sent to the recipients because of the mail
>   server failure. (Sending Mail using Account 5 (2017-02-02T14:28:22).
>   Exception Message: Cannot send mails to mail server. (The SMTP server
>   requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The
>   server response was: 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first.
>   n8sm30283000pgc.16 - gsmtp). )

Then again I have tried to change the port number 465 and got the below error

> The mail could not be sent to the recipients because of the mail
>   server failure. (Sending Mail using Account 4 (2017-02-02T14:28:19).
>   Exception Message: Cannot send mails to mail server. (Failure sending
>   mail.). )

Is there anything I am missing?
Note: I am trying this in Local Machine and I am able to send email from `C#` code with `Port 25`

Thank You.

Comment: Is SQL mail configured and tested?

Comment: I am following to this blog: http://surajpassion.in/sending-email-using-stored-procedures-in-sql-server/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in the Q&A [Sending email in .NET through Gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260/sending-email-in-net-through-gmail), on [MSDN: How to configure SQL Server Database Mail to send email using your Windows Live Mail Account or your GMail Account](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/suhde/2009/07/12/how-to-configure-sql-server-database-mail-to-send-email-using-your-windows-live-mail-account-or-your-gmail-account/) and so on, you need to use port 587 *and* a secure connection, as the error you received indicates:

> 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first

So, pass the `@enable_ssl=1` parameter to `sysmail_add_account_sp` as explained in [MSDN: sysmail_add_account_sp (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182804.aspx).