# Database mail not working properly

Tags: sql-server

I am bit confused sending e-mail via SQL Server 2008 Management Studio. I tried all remedies discussed in most threads, but unfortunately still having the issues. Can someone help me to resolve the matter? Much appreciated!

I am getting following error, when trying to send e-mail via SSMS

> The mail could not be sent to recipient because of the mail server failure...(SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was 5.7.0. Must issue a STARTTLScommand first

I checked my GMail user name and password, and properly defined profile and account, port used 587.

SMTP E-mail setup done at IIS (Windows 7 PC)

Kindly advise, how can I overcome the e-mail sending issue using SSMS?

Comment: Did you see the top comment here? https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2578/setup-sql-server-database-mail-to-use-a-gmail-hotmail-yahoo-or-aol-account/

Comment: you can find some of the useful information here as well : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41998085/unable-to-send-email-from-sql-server

Answer (score 0):

It's better to share the configuration which you have set for database mail, but anyways:

1. `STARTTLS` means the Gmail server is asking for authentication, and xp_smtp_sendmail  does not provide ways for getting authenticated with Gmail or Yahoo.
2. Check these links ... [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/suhde/2009/07/12/how-to-configure-sql-server-database-mail-to-send-email-using-your-windows-live-mail-account-or-your-gmail-account/) and [link](https://morecoding.wordpress.com/2014/05/12/sql-database-mail/) as I guess you have something wrong in your configuration there.